# what is the fastest way to find the gcd of n numbers?

Tags: algorithm, math, greatest-common-divisor

what is the fastest way to compute the greatest common divisor of n numbers?

Comment: finding GCD recursively is the fastest known method. Do you want some kind of special optimization?

Comment: @Gunner: The question is about the GCD of more than 2 arguments.

Comment: @ Marcelo Cantos: The concept is still same.

Comment: Every method I can think of that does not use the fact that gcd(a,b,c)=gcd(gcd(a,b),c) is slower.

Comment: Why do you ask? Using `gcd(a,b,c)=gcd(gcd(a,b),c)` is the best method, much faster in general than using for example factorization. In fact, for polynomials one uses `gcd` with the derivative first to find factors which occurs more than once.

Comment: I'd probably try to find the greatest common power of _base of number representation_ by counting common trailing zeros, followed by taking the remainder from dividing the second smallest number in set by the smallest - wait, this is just GCD from smallest to largest. Meh. Look for Lehmer and _why_ matrix multiplication helps it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Lehmer's GCD algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_GCD_algorithm).

Answer (score 20):

Without recursion:

```
int result = numbers[0];
for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){
    result = gcd(result, numbers[i]);
}
return result;
```

For very large arrays, it might be faster to use the fork-join pattern, where you split your array and calculate gcds in parallel. Here is some pseudocode:

```
int calculateGCD(int[] numbers){
    if(numbers.length <= 2){
        return gcd(numbers);    
    }
    else {
        INVOKE-IN-PARALLEL {
            left = calculateGCD(extractLeftHalf(numbers));
            right = calculateGCD(extractRightHalf(numbers));
        }
        return gcd(left,right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You may want to sort the numbers first and compute the gcd recursively starting from the smallest two numbers.

Answer (score 4):

**C++17**

I have written this function for calculating gcd of n numbers by using C++'s inbuilt `__gcd(int a, int b)` function.

```
int gcd(vector<int> vec, int vsize)
{
    int gcd = vec[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < vsize; i++)
    {
        gcd = __gcd(gcd, vec[i]);
    }
    return gcd;
}
```

To know more about this function visit [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) .

Also refer to [Dijkstra's GCD algorithm](https://www.cse.wustl.edu/~cytron/101Pages/f08/Notes/Recursion/recursion.html) from the following link. It works without division. So it could be slightly faster (Please correct me if I am wrong.)

Comment: (The subtraction version is what seems to have been presented by Euclid - and it was *old* when he did. Speed compared to remainder versions should be machine dependant.)

Answer (score 2):

How about the following using Euclidean algorithm by subtraction:

```js
function getGCD(arr){
    let min = Math.min(...arr); 
    let max= Math.max(...arr);
    if(min==max){
        return min;
    }else{
         for(let i in arr){
            if(arr[i]>min){
                arr[i]=arr[i]-min;
            }
        }
        return getGCD(arr);
    }
   
}

console.log(getGCD([2,3,4,5,6]))
```

The above implementation takes O(n^2) time. There are [improvements](https://codility.com/media/train/10-Gcd.pdf) that can be implemented but I didn't get around trying these out for n numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **a lot** of **small** numbers, factorization may be actually faster.

```
//Java
int[] array = {60, 90, 45};
int gcd = 1;
outer: for (int d = 2; true; d += 1 + (d % 2)) {
    boolean any = false;
    do {
        boolean all = true;
        any = false;
        boolean ready = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            ready &= (array[i] == 1);
            if (array[i] % d == 0) {
                any = true;
                array[i] /= d;
            } else all = false;
        }
        if (all) gcd *= d;
        if (ready) break outer;
    } while (any);
}
System.out.println(gcd);
```

(works for some examples, but not really tested)

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Euclidean algorithm** :

```
function gcd(a, b)
while b ≠ 0
   t := b; 
   b := a mod b; 
   a := t; 
return a;
```

You apply it for the first two numbers, then the result with the third number, etc... :

```
read(a);
read(b);

result := gcd(a, b);
i := 3;
while(i <= n){
    read(a)
    result := gcd(result, a);
}
print(result);
```

Comment: And in the cycle if you get '1' for the result you can stop the cycle

Answer (score 1):

Here below is the source code of the C program to find HCF of N numbers using Arrays.

```html
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,gcd;
    printf("Enter how many no.s u want to find gcd : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int arr[n];
    printf("\nEnter your numbers below :- \n ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter your %d number = ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    gcd=arr[0];
    int j=1;
    while(j<n)
    {
       if(arr[j]%gcd==0)
       {
           j++;
       }
       else
       {
           gcd=arr[j]%gcd;
           i++;
       }
    }
    printf("\nGCD of k no.s = %d ",gcd);
    return 0;
}
```

For more refer to this [website](http://www.codezclub.com/c-find-gcd-hcf-of-n-numbers/) for further clarification.......

Comment: There's a typo in the while's else block, should be `j++` instead of `i++`. Or even without this line. 
Be careful, with second `j++` it won't work properly 100% of times. For example in the array `[3166277268, 14314056372, 3166277268, 1241634933, 11582623668, 3353406672, 4050665157, 11002134528, 14642726637, 14183632848]` with `j++` it will return `7834365` without - `74613`

Answer (score 1):

You can use divide and conquer. To calculate gcdN([]), you divide the list into first half and second half. if it only has one num for each list. you calculate using gcd2(n1, n2).

I just wrote a quick sample code. (assuming all num in the list are positive Ints)

```
def gcdN(nums):
    n = len(nums)
    if n == 0: return "ERROR"
    if n == 1: return nums[0]
    if n >= 2: return gcd2(gcdN(nums[:n//2]), gcdN(nums[n//2:]))

def gcd2(n1, n2):
    for num in xrange(min(n1, n2), 0, -1):
        if n1 % num == 0 and n2 % num == 0:
            return num
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a gcd method that uses the property that gcd(a, b, c) = gcd(a, gcd(b, c)).
It uses BigInteger's gcd method since it is already optimized.

```
public static BigInteger gcd(BigInteger[] parts){
    BigInteger gcd = parts[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++)
        gcd = parts[i].gcd(gcd);
    return gcd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Recursive solution to get the GCD of Two Numbers

long long int gcd(long long int a,long long int b)<br>
{
   return b==0 ? a : gcd(b,a%b);
}
int main(){
  long long int a,b;
  cin>>a>>b;
  if(a>b) cout<<gcd(a,b);
  else cout<<gcd(b,a);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class GCDArray{
    public static int [] extractLeftHalf(int [] numbers)
    {
        int l =numbers.length/2;
        int arr[] = Arrays.copyOf(numbers, l+1);
        return arr;
    }

    public static int [] extractRightHalf(int [] numbers)
    {
        int l =numbers.length/2;
        int arr[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers,l+1, numbers.length);
        return arr;
    }

    public static int gcd(int[] numbers)
    {
        if(numbers.length==1)
            return numbers[0];
        else {
            int x = numbers[0];
            int y = numbers[1];
            while(y%x!=0)
            {
                int rem = y%x;
                y = x;
                x = rem;
            }
            return x;
        }
    }
    public static int gcd(int x,int y)
    {
            while(y%x!=0)
            {
                int rem = y%x;
                y = x;
                x = rem;
            }
            return x;

    }
    public static int calculateGCD(int[] numbers){
        if(numbers.length <= 2){
            return gcd(numbers);    
        }
        else {

                    int left = calculateGCD(extractLeftHalf(numbers));
                    int right = calculateGCD(extractRightHalf(numbers));

            return gcd(left,right);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(calculateGCD(arr));
    }
}
```

**

> Above is the java working code ..... the pseudo code of which is
>   already mention by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7412/dogbane

**

Comment: This is not adding any new information since the pseudocode is already their. Additionally this question is about a concept, not the practical implementation in any language.

Comment: ya you are right ...but i think it will be helpful for someone... but thanks for you comment :)

Comment: I definitely see your good intention here, but having such an answer means that we would also have to take similar answers for all other possible languages. This would make it really hard to find any usefull information here.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive JavaScript (ES6) one-liner for any number of digits.

```
const gcd = (a, b, ...c) => b ? gcd(b, a % b, ...c) : c.length ? gcd(a, ...c) : Math.abs(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what comes off the top of my head in Javascript.

```
function calculateGCD(arrSize, arr) {
    if(!arrSize)
        return 0;
    var n = Math.min(...arr);
    for (let i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = 0;
        while(j < arrSize) {
            if(arr[j] % i === 0) {
                j++;
            }else {
                break;
            }
            if(j === arrSize) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(generalizedGCD(4, [2, 6, 4, 8]));
// Output => 2
```

Comment: Please add an assessment of the number of operations needed. Compare it to one of the *pairwise GCD* approaches of pre-existing answers.

Answer (score -4):

Here was the answer I was looking for.
The best way to find the gcd of n numbers is indeed using recursion.ie gcd(a,b,c)=gcd(gcd(a,b),c). But I was getting timeouts in certain programs when I did this.

The optimization that was needed here was that the recursion should be solved using fast matrix multiplication algorithm.

Comment: An accepted answer with two down votes? This is why, I have trust issues.

Comment: There is a "half-GCD" algorithm used in GNU MultiPrecision, which purportedly uses matrix multiplication: [Subquadratic GCD](https://gmplib.org/manual/Subquadratic-GCD.html#Subquadratic-GCD), based on Niels Möller, “On Schönhage’s algorithm and subquadratic integer GCD computation”, in Mathematics of Computation, volume 77, January 2008, pp. 589-607. (From just squinting my eyes, GMP does not seem to directly support GCD of more than two numbers.)