# Get the gcd of n numbers

Tags: java, math, greatest-common-divisor

This could seem an easy question but I cannot find a solution. I must find the gcd of n numbers.

```
public int getGCD(int a, int b) {
 if (b == 0) { return a; }
 else { return getGCD(b, a%b); }
}
```

This is the popular recursive way that calculates the gcd of **two** numbers. But if I need to get the gcd of 3, 4, 5... n numbers? I was thinking to do something like this:

```
public int getGCD(int[] a) {
 //the code  
}
```

There is an array of integer as parameter, but I have no idea about the code. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351195/finding-the-gcd-of-n-numbers

Comment: The question is apparently a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231733/euclidian-greatest-common-divisor-for-more-than-two-numbers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The GCD of a multiple numbers `gcd( n1, n2, .... nx )` can be computed by incrementally computing the GCD of two numbers:

```
gcd( n1, n2, .... nx ) == gcd( n1, gcd( n2, gcd( ... , nx ) ) )
```

Every divisor for all numbers, has to be a divisor for any subset of these numbers. Which in turn leads to the above formula.

By reusing your given `getGCD(int, int)` function for two numbers, we can create an additional overload that takes a list of one or more numbers:

```
public int getGCD(int a, int b) {
 // implementation for two numbers goes here
}

public int getGCD(int[] a) {
  // the GCD of a number with itself is... itself
  int gcd = a[0];

  // compute incrementally
  for( int i=1; i<a.length; i++ ) {
    gcd = getGCD( gcd, a[i] );
  }

  // return result
  return gcd;    
}
```

Comment: note that the original function and the new function are now named the same. Change the original to sth. else..

Comment: The function takes an int[] and you're passing two int values. Is it correct?

Comment: @WampieDriessen stop nit-picking. An OP should be able to follow from this sort of ***example***.

Comment: @DK64 Added your function and renamed mine, to make it more obvious which function is which.

Comment: @Sirko In Java, it was better using the overloaded method names.

Comment: @280Z28 But obviously it lead to some confusion for OP here. In general, though, I agree (see the first version of the function).

Comment: @Sirko I cleaned up the wording. Also I remove the implementation details for two numbers since the algorithm it used was not particularly desirable and I didn't want it to detract from the rest of your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Try with this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(" GDC: " + getGdc(12, 48, 24, 5));
    System.out.println(" GDC: " + getGdc(12, 48, 24));
}

public static int getGdc(int... x) {
    // get the smallest of all number no need to check for higher values
    int smallest = getSmallest(x);

    for(int i = smallest; i >= 1; i--) {
       int j;
       for(j = 0; j < x.length; ++j) {
           if(x[j] % i != 0)
               break;
       }
       // if we pass through the array with all % == 0 return the value
       if(j == x.length)
           return i;
    }
    // so the only possible is 1
    return 1;
}

// return smallest number of an array of int
public static int getSmallest(int[] x) {
    int smallest = x[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < x.length; ++i) {
        if(x[i] < smallest)
            smallest = x[i];
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Refer [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/224151-find-the-gcd-using-arrays/) also for more. Hope this helps

Comment: Good use of the smallest number heuristic.  This will definitely run faster than the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

Java’s latest features can come in handy here.  The idea is that we take the first two numbers from `a`, find their gcd, and put that back in `a`.  This is exactly what a [reduce](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) operation does (although I’ll use the reduce for an `intStream`).

You then have:

```
public int getGCD(int[] a) {
    Arrays.stream(a).reduce( (b,c) -> getGCD(b,c) ).getAsInt();
}
```

You may be able to replace the lambda expression with a method reference:

```
    Arrays.stream(a).reduce(ClassName::getGCD).getAsInt();
```

(Although I’m assuming the compiler will know you’re referring to `getGCD(int,int)`.  If it complains, you’d have to rename a method.)

Answer (score 0):

```
package may23;
/**
 * 
 * @author Ramkumar Raja
 *
 */
public class GcdofArrayNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int arr[]={8,16,80};
        int temp=0;
        for(int i =0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                temp=gcdArray(arr[i+1], arr[i]);
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                temp=gcdArray(temp, arr[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Gcd"+temp);


    }

    public static int gcdArray(int a,int b)
    {
        int gcd=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=a && i<=b;i++)
        {
            if(a%i==0 && b%i==0)
            {
                gcd=i;
            }

        }

        return gcd;

    }

}
```