# Generating Number Pairs and GCD in Java

Tags: java, prime-factoring, greatest-common-divisor

**Problem:** Given A,B print the number of pairs (a,b) such that GCD(a,b)=1 and 1<=a<=A and 1<=b<=B.

**Solution (Brute Force Approach)**
In the below code, i have used brute force approach and it works fine. However the execution time is more 10 sec if A & B > 10^5

**Alternative Solution**
From my research i found out that finding prime factors of A & B will reduce the execution time considerably (< 3 sec), but i'm not sure how to apply it.

**Need Help:**
Can anyone help me to arrive at the result with < 3 sec execution time?

```
class GCD {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int A = 0, B = 0, GCD = 0, count = 0;
    BigInteger B1, B2 = null;

    A = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    B = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    for (int a = 1; a <= A; a++) {
        for (int b = 1; b <= B; b++) {
            B1 = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
            B2 = BigInteger.valueOf(b);
            GCD = calculateGCD(B1, B2);
            if (GCD == 1) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}

public static int calculateGCD(BigInteger number1, BigInteger number2) {
    return (number1.gcd(number2)).intValue();
}
}
```

Comment: here is an idea how to calculate the gcd efficiently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885537/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-the-gcd-of-n-numbers

Comment: Do you know how to find the prime factorization of a number? Start by writing a method `factor` that returns a `List` of the appropriate numeric type. Additionally, is using `BigInteger` required? It's a good bit slower than `long`.

Comment: Now i have 2 Lists which contains the prime factors of A and B. But im not sure how to proceed further with those prime factors.

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to write a complete programm or something, but I want to give you some tips for speeding up your program:

1. `gcd(a,b) = gcd(b,a)` so only compute pairs `(a, b)` with `a < b`. `gcd(a,a) = 1` holds only for `a = 1`. Also `gcd(1,b) = 1` for all `b`, so you can start with `a = 2` and a `count = 1 + 2*(B-1)`.
2. compute all primefactors for all `1 < a <= A` at once by using something like the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). E.g. every secound number contains primefactor 2, every third the primfactor 3.
3. You do not need to compute the gcd. Let `a` contain the distinct primfactors `p` and `q`. Then you know:

   - There are `B-a` numbers to test.
   - Every `p`-th number contains also the primfactor `p`, every `q`-th primenumber also contains the primfactor `q`. `floor( (B-a)/p )` numbers have a `gcd >= p` and `floor( (B-a)/q )` numbers have a `gcd >= q` and `floor( (B-a)/(p*q) )` numbers have you counted twice. So you can get the number of pairs `(a,b)` with `a < b` as
     `(B-a) - floor( (B-a)/p ) - floor( (B-a)/q ) + floor( (B-a)/(p*q) )`
   - if you want also the pairs it self, you can use a for-loop and jump every step where `i` (for-loop counter) is divisable by any primefactor of `a`

I think this should speed up your program as much as you need to reach less than a second.