# Not able to understand why on some particular test cases it shows segmentation faults while on others it is successfully accepted

Tags: c

I'm trying to answer the following assignment:

> We are given two arrays `a` and `b` containing elements each.
>
> Choose a pair of elements `(x,y)` such that: `x` belongs to array `a`; `y` belongs to array `b`;  `gcd(x,y)` is the maximum of all pairs `(x,y)`.
>
> If there is more than one such pair having maximum gcd, then choose the one with maximum sum.
>
> Print the sum of elements of this maximum-sum pair.
>
> `n` -> size of the input arrays
>
> `a` and `b` are two arrays consisting of `n` numbers each.

This code is showing segmentation fault.  I can't figure out the problem.
 it is showing segmentation fault for some test cases while for other it runs perfectly.Can you figure out the problem with the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

long int max_gcd=0,max_sum=0;
long int n;
long int a[1000000],b[1000000];

long int hcf(long int n1, long int n2)
{
    if (n2 != 0)
        return hcf(n2, n1%n2);
    else
        return n1;
}
long int gcd(long int i,long int j,long int n)
{   
long int ans=hcf(a[i],b[j]);
    if(ans>max_gcd)
    {
        max_gcd=ans;
        max_sum=a[i]+b[j];
    }
    if(ans==max_gcd && max_sum<a[i]+b[j])
    {
        max_sum=a[i]+b[j];
    }
    if(j+1<n)
        return gcd(i,j+1,n);
    else if(i+1<n)
        return gcd(i+1,0,n);
    return max_sum;
}
int main()
{ 
    long int i;
    scanf("%ld",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%ld",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%ld",&b[i]);
    }
    long int ans=gcd(0,0,n);
    printf("%ld",ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Please read and follow [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), thanks.

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: Probably array indexes out of bounds. You can check this easily yourself.

Comment: here we are given two arrays a  and b  containing  elements each. we need to Choose a pair of elements(x,y)  such that:

x belongs to array a .
y belongs to array b.
gcd(x,y) is the maximum of all pairs(x,y) .
If there is more than one such pair  having maximum gcd, then choose the one with maximum sum. we need to Print the sum of elements of this maximum-sum pair.

Comment: @coder09 don't post clarifications in comments but edit your question and put them _there_. And what are those particular test cases where the program fails??

Comment: Can you use a debugger to pinpoint the issue?

Comment: @Marievi n declared Global in above section

Comment: You need to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) & you should include the test cases where you get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code requires unspecified input to run - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: @Marievi, `n` appears to be a global (line 4).

Comment: it's an online coding competition question I guess....that's why test cases are hidden...

Comment: The array just contain some random numbers all positive integers...given at runtime....

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885537/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-the-gcd-of-n-numbers) convert the answers to your need.

Answer (score 1):

You should not ask running contest's question. Better try it by own or wait for editorial. Don't abide contest rule.
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w34/challenges/maximum-gcd-and-sum